# Python sum list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've been trying to sum a list of dictionaries but I keep getting the error "Object  is not iterable". I'm really new to python so I dont even know if my constructor is correct, maybe someone can help?

```
    class Solution:

    def __init__(self, solution = []):
        self.solution = solution

    def getWeight(self):
        print(sum(item["weight"] for item in solution))


solution = Solution([
        {"name": "diamond", "weight": 20, "value": 1050},
        {"name": "laptop", "weight": 550, "value": 320}
        ])

solution.getWeight()
```

Comment: As a general tip: This looks like code written by somebody coming from Java. In Python, we don't need to wrap everything in classes. A simple module level function will do the job just fine here unless you are planning on adding extra methods to your class.

Comment: Aside from that: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or **complete error message** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: In `getWeight`, you'll need to use `self.solution` instead of just `solution`.

Comment: Also, be careful when using a mutable object (like a list) as a default parameter (like in your `__init__`).  See here: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: @0x5453 that's a good tip, thanks!

Comment: @timgeb yes that's actually true, java was the first language I learned and now I'm trying to learn python as well, thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is in this line:

```
 print(sum(item["weight"] for item in solution))
```

You need to specify that "solution" here is the solution variable inside the class.
Try:

```
print(sum(item["weight"] for item in self.solution))
```

Comment: this works thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are summing incorrectly in the sense that `solution` is an argument passed to `__init__` but accessible to other methods in the class by using the `self` instance as `self.solution`. While your summing method is correct using `( )`, an alternative would be to use a list comprehension to collect the items and then use `sum`.

```
def getWeight(self):
    print(sum([item["weight"] for item in self.solution]))
```

Comment: The summing in the OP is fine, you don't need to use an intermediate list comprehension to collect the items.  When inside parenthesis, (e.g. as an argument to a function like `sum`,) the expression `item["weight"] for item in self.solution` results in a generator that `sum` is able to iterate over.  And actually, using a generator expression like this will be a bit more efficient since it doesn't need to build up that intermediate list.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I saw this as an alternative solution personally being a fan of list comprehensions. :) Let me rephrase it